# Get values of all string properties in current class instance

Tags: c#, reflection

I'd like to implement a public getter which will get values of all string properties in current class instance and return it as concatinated string.

```
public class BaseViewModel
    {
        public string AllProperties => GetType().GetProperties().Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, prop) => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) ? current + (string)prop.GetValue(this, null) : current);
    }

public class ChildViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this I get StackOverflowException..

Comment: You could also use string.Concat: string.Concat(GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) && prop.Name != nameof(AllProperties)).Select(property => (string)property.GetValue(this, null))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you end up querying `AllProperties` recursively.

And `.Where(property => property.Name != "AllProperties")` after `GetProperties ()` to exclude it.

So it looks like this:

```
public string AllProperties => GetType().GetProperties().
    Where(property => property.Name != "AllProperties").
    Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, prop) => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) ? current + (string)prop.GetValue(this, null) : current);
```

Comment: Looks like I need more coffee.. Thank you so much!